# Hide keyboard when showing SLComposeViewController alerts with No twitter Accounts found

Tags: twitter, ios7, keyboard, uialertview, social-framework

I am using the following code for showing the alert for no twitter account configured in settings app of device.

```
SLComposeViewController *viewController = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
viewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
//hide tweet sheet
viewController.view.hidden = YES;
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
//hide the keyboard
[viewController.view endEditing:YES];
```

It is working perfectly fine except that it is not hiding the keyboard. Basically I just want the UIAlertView that can direct users to the settings app. Since the alert view is handled by the social framework, I am unable to find the exact point where I can place the code to hide the keyboard. I can hide the Tweet sheet by    `viewController.view.hidden = YES;`

Can someone please suggest me so as how to hide the keyboard?